# Ruby - Instance_of? / is_a not working

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with is_a and instance_of functions.

I have an array to which I add items, however, I want that only if an item which is kind of a specific class type will be allowed to be added.

I have the following code:

```
def add_item(new_item)
  new_item.is_a?(classA) do
    @items << new_item
end

new_item.instance_of?(classA) do
    @items << new_item
end
```

where items is the array and classA is a class I defined in my code.

None of them works and the item is not being added although the item I send to function is of type classA:

```
new_item = classA.new('text', 'text2')
```

It will be great if someone can assist with the issue.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if new_item.is_a?(classA)
  @items << new_item
end
```

`is_a?` is a method which returns true or false. As every method in ruby it can take a block, and as most of the methods it does absolutely nothing with it. So your `<<` has never been executed.

Comment: Thank you.. I can't believe I forgot the if statement. Sorry for that. That what happens when you code after midnight I guess.